# Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ has a finite range, then it has a convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ has a finite range, then it has a convergent subsequence.

Here is what I have, but I don't think its enough.

Since $\{a_n\}$ has a finite range.  Then we can say the sequence is bounded.  Since the sequence is bounded, then it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: You can have a *bounded* sequence with *finite range*, but still being *divergent*.

For example, $s_n = i^n$ does not converge, but it is bounded and it has a finite range.

$s_n = \left\{i, -1, -i, 1, i, ... \right\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, $\{a_n\}$ must have a constant subsequence. Since the range is finite, if each element in the range appeared only a finite number of times then the sequence would only have finitely many terms. Hence one element must appear infinitely often. This is your convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Since it has a finite range, there must be some $y$ in the range such that $\{n\in\Bbb N:a_n=y\}$ is infinite. A constant sequence is convergent.